# Sharing row in a union - group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id, SUM( orderLineTotal ) as orderLine1, NULL as orderLine 2
   FROM Orders
   WHERE Orders.Date < @Today
   GROUP BY id

   UNION

   SELECT id, NULL as orderLine1, SUM(orderLineTotal2) as orderLine 2
   FROM Orders
   WHERE Orders.Date = @Today
   GROUP BY id
) o
GROUP BY o.id, o.orderLine1, o.orderLine2
```

I'm getting back a result like this:

```
 ID         OrderLine1          OrderLine2
 -----------------------------------------
 1          105.00              NULL
 1          NULL                204.00
 2          49.30               NULL
 2          NULL                94.24
```

Is there any way to modify the query to return something like this?

```
 ID         OrderLine1          OrderLine2
 -----------------------------------------
 1          105.00              204.00
 2          49.30                94.24
```

Comment: The quickest way would be to take advantage of your aggegation and change the select logic to `SELECT ID, Max(OrderLine1), Max(OrderLine2)`, but @GordonLinoff answer is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do this with one query and conditional aggregation:

```
   SELECT id,
          SUM(case when Orders.Date < @Today then orderLineTotal end) as orderLine1, 
          SUM(case when Orders.Date = @Today then orderLineTotal2 end) as orderLine2
   FROM Orders
   GROUP BY id
```

By the way, are there really two columns, `orderLineTotal` and `orderLineTotal2`?  I suspect there is only one and the second `sum()` should change accordingly.

Comment: You are correct in that assumption. I greatly simplified my query to try to help clarify.